# TypeError: 'getUserMedia' webrtc adapter.debug.js

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

All of the sudden i get this error in Firefox 45.0.2 .
TypeError: 'getUserMedia' called on an object that does not implement interface MediaDevices.
Working well in Chrome and Opera.

To find out what's wrong in my code i decided to take a look at the demo to see how that would behave in firefox.

AdapterJS/demo/MediaStream.html

`getusermedia.html:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: getUserMedia is not defined`

***updated with the actual function that invokes getUserMedia***

```
 function captureUserMedia(callback) {
$('#videoSource').css('display', 'none');
var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
var constraints = null;
constraints = {
    video: {

        optional: [{
            sourceId: videoSource
        }]
    },
    audio: false
}
var htmlElement = document.getElementById('rtcvideo') ||    document.getElementsByTagName('object');
htmlElement.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
htmlElement.setAttribute('controls', true);

var mediaConfig = {
    video: htmlElement,
    onsuccess: function(stream) {
        config.attachStream = stream;
        video = attachMediaStream(video, stream);
        callback && callback();
        htmlElement.setAttribute('muted', true);
        rotateInCircle(htmlElement);
    },
    onerror: function() {
        alert('unable to get access to your webcam');
    }
};
getUserMedia(constraints, mediaConfig.onsuccess, mediaConfig.onerror);
streamAttached = true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is you're using the [Temasys](https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS/blob/master/demo/MediaStream.html) version. I recommend switching to the [official adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill instead.

Comment: Can you please post some code? and like @jib said are you using the official adapter.js polyfill?

Comment: I'm using AdapterJS.VERSION = '0.12.3'; It DID work in Firefox previously. If i use ie the official adapter.js getuserMedia doesn't even exist and there's trouble with require in ./utils.

Answer (score 2):

Update you written：

```
navigator.getUserMedia({"audio":true, "video":true}, gotUserMedia, didntGetUserMedia);
myVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(myVideoStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not let the Script wait until the user allowed the use of getUserMedia(). Let your JavaScript  just wait a little bit.

Comment: I  had a similar problem some weeks ago.

Comment: and by pausing you mean i set a timeout on the getUserMedia?

Comment: You just set a timeout for your JS before accessing the getUserMedia(). It works on Chrome and Opera because they remind your decision for getUserMedia().

Comment: Getusermedia is invoked when a user hits a playbutton.

Comment: This is the problem. When the User taps your button, than your program wants to directly use the getUserMedia Device. But you don't give the user enough time to allow the use of the Debice.

Comment: Using their cdn with the latest version seems to work. https://cdn.temasys.com.sg/adapterjs/0.13.2/adapter.debug.js . And not for the first time in Firefox on W8 FF crashes all the time. On other machines in FF working well.

Answer (score 0):

using the latest adapter.debug.js 13.3 solved it.